# items not aligning correctly in safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, flexbox

An element in my action bar just won't stay put in **Safari and on ipad**. It even moves up and down irregular (as you can see in the two different images below). Since chrome on ipad is build on the safari webkit engine it should be something with doing with that.

I can't seem to find the solution.

In the images below you can see it starts with `div.profile`.

```
nav .profile {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

There is more code, but that I put in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynwvvzt0/).
Bootstrap 3 is used and I'm using flexbox, might be worth mentioning.

Anybody knows more

[image]
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ynwvvzt0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css.

```
nav a.icon, nav .profile, nav .profile div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```